# Prevent space in tag text of select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am facing some problem on creating tag without space in select2. When I press like tt then created a new tag, if I write tt again it is preventing but when I press “tt tt” then creating new tag. I want to prevent space between two tt and tt. No space is allowed into this tag. How could I do that? Thanks in advance.

**CODE**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#pictures_tag_input").select2({
        tags: true,
        multiple: true,
        placeholder: "Please type here",
        maximumSelectionSize: 12,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
        createTag: function(params) {
          // empty string is not allow
          var term = $.trim(params.term);
          if (term === "") {
            return null;
          }
    
          // duplicate check
          var selectedTags = $("#pictures_tag_input").val() || [];
          if (selectedTags.indexOf(term) > -1) {
            return null;
          }
    
          return {
            id: term,
            text: term,
            newTag: true // add additional parameters
          };
        },
        templateResult: function(item) {
          return item.name || item.text;
        },
        templateSelection: function(item) {
          return item.name || item.text;
        },
        escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
          return markup;
        },
        ajax: {
          url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/444cr",
          dataType: "json",
          global: false,
          cache: true,
          delay: 0,
          data: function(params) {
            return {
              q: params.term
            };
          },
          processResults: function(results, params) {
            // remove existing tag after key press
            var term = $.trim(params.term);
            var searchedTags = $.map(results, function(tag) {
              if (tag.text.match(term) || term === "")
                return { id: tag.id, text: tag.text };
            });
            return {
              results: searchedTags
            };
          } //end of process results
        } // end of ajax
      });
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <form id="frm">
    <h1>Sample Form</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tagInput">Tag Input</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="pictures_tag_input"></select>
          <small class="form-text text-muted"><p class="text-info">1) no space in tag 2) create tag dynamically 3) prevent duplicate tag 4) search tag from ajax calling 5) tag create by enter, space and comma 6) at first dot, @ are not allow 7) sometimes tag popup position is not right placed.</p></small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

> N.B: select2 version is 4.0.5

Here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/daVZNo?editors=1010) link
https://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/daVZNo?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I want to prevent space between two tt and tt. 
>   You can achieve it in two different ways:

**First method:**
in your create tag search for element starting with..... From:

```
if (selectedTags.indexOf(term) > -1) {
   return null;
}
```

TO:

```
var dups = selectedTags.findIndex(function(e) {
       return e  == term.substr(0, e.length + 1).trim();
})
```

**Second method:**
Use [select2:selecting](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) in order to prevent new tags starting with unwanted prefix:

```
.on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
    if (e.params.args.data.newTag) {
        var term = e.params.args.data.text;
        var selectedTags = $("#pictures_tag_input").val() || [];
        var dups = selectedTags.findIndex(function(e) {
            return e  == term.substr(0, e.length + 1).trim();
        })
        if (dups != -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
   }
});
```

In this way, if you want only to avoid space in a new tag you may simply prevend default action if a space is contained in the new tag text.

```js
$("#pictures_tag_input").select2({
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Please type here",
    maximumSelectionSize: 12,
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
    createTag: function (params) {
        // empty string is not allow
        var term = $.trim(params.term);

        if (term === "") {
            return null;
        }

        // duplicate check
        var selectedTags = $("#pictures_tag_input").val() || [];
        var dups = selectedTags.findIndex(function (e) {
            return (e.length <= term.length) && (e == term.substr(0, e.length + 1).trim());
        })
        if (dups != -1) {
            return null;
        }

        return {
            id: term,
            text: term,
            selected: true,
            newTag: true // add additional parameters
        };
    },
    templateResult: function (item) {
        return item.name || item.text;
    },
    templateSelection: function (item) {
        return item.name || item.text;
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    },
    ajax: {
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/444cr",
        dataType: "json",
        global: false,
        cache: true,
        delay: 0,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (results, params) {
            // remove existing tag after key press
            var term = $.trim(params.term);
            var searchedTags = $.map(results, function (tag) {
                if (tag.text.match(term) || term === "")
                    return {id: tag.id, text: tag.text};
            });
            return {
                results: searchedTags
            };
        } //end of process results
    } // end of ajax
}).on('select2:selecting', function (e) {
    if (e.params.args.data.newTag) {
        var term = e.params.args.data.text;
        var selectedTags = $("#pictures_tag_input").val() || [];
        var dups = selectedTags.findIndex(function (e) {
            return (e.length < term.length) && (e == term.substr(0, e.length + 1).trim());
        })
        if (dups != -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}).on('select2:opening', function (e) {
    var val = $(this).data().select2.$container.find('input');
    if ($(this).val().indexOf(val.val()) != -1) {
        val.val('');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <form id="frm">
        <h1>Sample Form</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pictures_tag_input">Tag Input</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="pictures_tag_input">
                    </select>
                    <small class="form-text text-muted"><p class="text-info">1) no space in tag 2) create tag dynamically 3) prevent duplicate tag 4) search tag from ajax calling 5) tag create by enter, space and comma 6) at first dot, @ are not allow 7) sometimes tag popup position is not right placed.</p></small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Bro, I have lost my other functionality, just check by the following way. just type "tag"  and press space, then type "tag" and choose any values tag2, tag3, and see the error. The "tag" is duplicate. please help me.

Comment: @Shohel Hi friend, sorry for the delay, I remove a comment in the snippet anf now it works. The comment: if (dups != -1) return null;   Let me know Thanks

Comment: Bro, at first choose "tag1" then type "tag", here is the selection problem, "tag1" is selected but need "tag" selection. how could i do that bro?

Comment: @Shohel Added a minor fix to my snippet. I hope this could help you

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all whitespaces from the tag?

```
var term = $.trim(params.term).replace(/\s/g,'');
```

Then `tt tt` will become `tttt`, the rest of the functionality still work. Applying to your codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeRoOv?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code:

```
$(document).on('keydown',".select2-search__field",function(e){  
   if (e.which === 32)  
      return false;  
});
```

Use `Keydown` event. When a key is pressed, the function will get the `keycode`.
The condition will check the `keycode` and if the spacebar is pressed it will return false.
This will "disable" spacebar and prevent space in tag text of select2.